# Language confusion with Finnish province and city names in Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

You show some province/region names in Swedish, some in Finnish.

- In a [job listing](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/15676/senior-java-developer-pandia-oy?a=iwiOIsU) we posted yesterday: "Espoo, **Uusimaa**, Finland"
- In [another listing](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/15703/java-developer-vaadin?a=iyhrqCI) posted today: "Turku, **Egentliga Finland**, Finland"

Now, *Egentliga Finland* is Swedish and would be *Varsinais-Suomi* in Finnish. *Uusimaa* is Finnish and would be *Nyland* in Swedish.

Here's a [list of all province/region names in Finnish](http://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suomen_maakunnat#Toiminnallis-taloudelliset_maakunnat_vuodesta_1994). Swedish is a 5% minority language in Finland, so you can pretty safely use the Finnish version for all provinces. (Except probably [Åland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85land) (Ahvenanmaa), which is fully Swedish-speaking.) In fact, in the case of Finland, **it would not matter at all if it just said "Turku, Finland", leaving out the province completely**.

Also, when submitting the ad, the UI kept showing the city as Esbo (Swedish for Espoo), even though we tried really hard to write "Espoo". But fortunately that changed after it was posted.

I'm sure this seems rather peripheral to you over there in America, but you really should iron out these kind of details at some point. Maybe eventually Careers would see more adoption over here too. (These two are the first ever Finnish ads I've seen on SO Careers.)

Comment: Oh, if this bug was *consistent*, it would say "Åbo, Egentliga Finland", using the Swedish name for the city too.

Comment: So Vaadin is in fact a Finnish product and is a pun on "palvelin"? If it is, that's hilarious. I always suspected this but never knew

Comment: +1 for pioneering careers in Finland!

Comment: Yeah, Vaadin is a Finnish product/company. If it's a pun on "palvelin", I never realised that... I've heard them explain the name meaning [female reindeer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaadin). (See e.g. the cover of *[Learning Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/845756)*.) Curiously, "vaadin" is also the 1st person singular conjugation of [vaatia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaatia), meaning "I demand".

Comment: @Jonik thanks for the info! Yeah, the verb form of "(minä) vaadin" made me think it's a pun on "palvelin" = "a thing that serves" - because "vaadin" could also mean "a thing that demands" (but I can be way off. I don't know whether anything about the product would justify the pun.)

Comment: Helsinki becomes Helsingfors! I understand it is a Swedish town name, but I do find that a little ridiculous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a fair amount of cached geocoding results on our side. We generally exclude states/regions now, but some older locations still have old names.

I updated the locations you mention, and the jobs should display as you suggest. Cached data will still exist, so feel free to get in touch where you see inconsistent or undesirable data. Thanks!

Comment: But what if I'm in `Springfield, USA`? (I guess one can always find out more by going to the employer's site, though.)

Comment: @TheP.G.RepMiningCo.: Are you allowed to use Java there?

Comment: Can you also look at the problem @Hannele reported (see comment on the question)? (Helsinki should always be used, not Helsingfors.)

Comment: Matt, the "city names in Swedish" problem still prevails. See e.g. [this ad](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/18443/sc5-finland-s-leading-html5-production-house-is-sc5?a=lN0GTra) which says "Helsingfors, Finland" instead of "Helsinki, Finland". (Btw, now there seem to be more Finnish job ads on Careers compared to when I posted the question.)

Comment: @Jonik Yes, we’ve confirmed the problem ([here](http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=helsinki&flags=X)) is with our geocode provider and we are working to use a different API. It should be online early next week.