# "Tampere Theatre" and "Espoo railway station" are not actually Finnish cities

Tags: bug, jobs

Doing a company search for Finland: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?location=finland, I'm confronted with rather strange place names:

[image]

Correct city names in these cases would be **Tampere** and **Espoo**. (See e.g. http://www.futuremark.com/contact if you don't believe me.)

Yes, the bug is probably in some location API that you use. ([You have had localisation oddities with Finnish place names earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116173/language-confusion-with-finnish-province-and-city-names-in-careers).) Still, should be fixed, whoever is to blame.

Comment: Poor Viima hasn't had such a good year and now resides in a fast-food stall at the station. Must you add salt to the wounds by pointing it out publicly?

Comment: It's Yahoo! fault. Really!

Comment: Yeah we actually can blame Yahoo again, this time for labeling Finnish railways stations and theaters as cities. As a thank you to Finland for bringing us Lordi and Sonata Arctica, I've manually fixed Tampere and Espoo in our geo database, so those company pages should now be displayed correctly.