# Weston-super-Mare - incorrect case

Tags: bug, profile-page, location

Was trying to change my address on Stack Overflow to 'Weston-super-Mare' (UK) and was prompted to use 'Weston-Super-Mare' (note the incorrect case for 'super')

> [image]

Can this be changed in the list of locations?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weston-super-Mare

I overrode it and typed it in correctly, so it's not affecting me, I just think it should be corrected in the main list.

Comment: I'm not sure but I assume that they use an external sevice. On carreers it is Yahoo. So I assume this can only be fixed by the service provider...

Comment: @rene You're probably right. If someone can confirm the service provider I'll look at contacting them about it.

Comment: I based my comment on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36646/158100)

Comment: @rene Helpful, thanks.

Comment: On Yahoo maps, if I search, I initially get a placemarker, with the capital 'S', in slightly the wrong place, but subsequent searches bring back the correct one in the correct place.

Comment: Well, it's Yahoo!'s fault, that's what their API is returning: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&callback=jQuery17109925915210042149_1403618984414&q=select+woeid%2C+name%2C+country%2C+placeTypeName%2C+admin1%2C+admin2%2C+admin3++from+geo.places+where+text%3D%22Weston-super-Mare%22&_=1403619217835

Comment: Yahoo's location database is FUBAR. [What else is new?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214130/tampere-theatre-and-espoo-railway-station-are-not-actually-finnish-cities)

Comment: Oh dear. Imagine the pony fans living in a place named "super-Mare".

Comment: I've added a 'user voice' entry for 'Global Maps' if anyone wants to vote for it...
https://yahoo.uservoice.com/forums/196503-global-maps/suggestions/6165466-misspelled-location-weston-super-mare-super-has